# How can I put MediaRecorder output in avformat_open_input?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, android-mediarecorder

I want to use ffmpeg to process the video stream from Android MediaRecorder.

It is known that the output of the camera in a local socket instead of a file !

```
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mSender.getFileDescriptor());
```

where mSender is a local socket.

Related code can see [spydroid-ipcamera](http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/).

Now I want to use ffmpeg to process it.
How can I put MediaRecorder output in avformat_open_input?

```
avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, ????, NULL, NULL)
```

What should be put in ????